# mark 2 rows in html table

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

Lets say i have a HTML table binded with data using knockout observable array.

Now i want user to be able to select max 2 rows. When he selects 2 rows then i will enable a button. Clicking on that button will select values from 2 rows and pass to my WCF service.

I mean i am trying to achieve same functionality where we can compare 2 files. For example in TFS when we select any of file and view history of file. Then we can select 2 rows in list and right click on it and select compare.

I just need examples to start with if any using jquery.

Do let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Comment: How user can select data? is there any checkbox to select?

Comment: you could addClass on row click, and count it..

Comment: @Manoj No i am looking for ideas. I know we can use checkbox and check if max 2 are selected. Looking for something better

Comment: @reyaner do you know how to do it? Is there any example

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var count = 1;
    $("table").on("click", "tr", function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass("selected")){
            $this.removeClass("selected");
            count--;
        }else{
            if(count < 3){
                $this.addClass("selected");
                count++;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Knockout solution.

The view is prety simple, two columns. The first for the checkbox and the second for a value.

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected, enable: $parent.selectionAllowed() || selected()" />
            </td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: value" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is view model :

```
var Item = function (parent, value) {
    var self = this;
    var parent = parent;
    self.value = value;

    self.selected = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return parent.selectedItems.indexOf(self) >= 0;
        },
        write: function (sel) {
            if (sel) {
                parent.selectedItems.push(self);
            } else {
                parent.selectedItems.remove(self);
            }
        }

    });
};

var VM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();

    self.selectionAllowed = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.selectedItems().length < 2;
    });


    self.items = ko.utils.arrayMap(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], function (item) {
        return new Item(self, item);
    });


};
var vm = new VM();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

- When an item is selected this item is pushed in the selectedItems array of the view model.
- When an item is unselected this item is removed.

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AznqD/5/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you do without checkbox? Just click on row to select the entire row. Dont want to use checkbox